# Scale selected image in Android image gallery

Tags: android, bitmapfactory

I have a question regarding scaling down the selected image in image gallery so i can upload it to a server via php.

So the order of action are:

1)Get selected image from gallery (DONE)

2)Scale it down and compress it to jpg (Got stucked here)

3)Upload to server async(DONE)

I need to connect 1st and 3rd step.So far i have done this:

**GET SELECTED IMAGE:**

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();

            Bitmap yourSelectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath); 

            new async_upload().execute(picturePath.toString());
        }

    }
```

**ASYNC UPLOAD IT:**

```
public class async_upload extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
            uploadFile(arg0[0]);
            return "asd";
        }

        @Override       
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        }
    } 

     public int uploadFile(String sourceFileUri) {
..............Code for uploading works.......
}
```

And my function for scaling  down the image.

```
private Bitmap decodeUri(Uri selectedImage) throws FileNotFoundException {

        // Decode image size
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImage), null, o);

        // The new size we want to scale to
        final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 640;

        // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
        int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;
        int scale = 1;
        while (true) {
            if (width_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE
               || height_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE) {
                break;
            }
            width_tmp /= 2;
            height_tmp /= 2;
            scale *= 2;
        }

        // Decode with inSampleSize
        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize = scale;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImage), null, o2);

    }
```

As you can see i am sending the URI of the selected image to `uploadFile` to be uploaded async. 
My problem is how can i "make a copy" of the selected image,compress/scale and send this image instead of the original one. Of course i dont want to alter the user's images...but send a scaled version.

Any ideas?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do something along these lines

```
File pngDir = new   File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"PicUploadTemp");
               if (!pngDir.exists()) {
            pngDir.mkdirs();
            }
             pngfile = new File(pngDir,"texture1.jpg");

             FileOutputStream fOut;
            try {
                    fOut = new FileOutputStream(pngfile);
                     finalbitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPG, 100,fOut);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            pngUri = Uri.fromFile(pngfile);
```

for the code you put up first add this method to your class

```
public static int calculateInSampleSize(
            BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

        // Calculate ratios of height and width to requested height and width
        final int heightRatio = Math.round((float) height / (float) reqHeight);
        final int widthRatio = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);

        // Choose the smallest ratio as inSampleSize value, this will guarantee
        // a final image with both dimensions larger than or equal to the
        // requested height and width.
        inSampleSize = heightRatio < widthRatio ? heightRatio : widthRatio;
    }

    return inSampleSize;
    }
```

then in your code that you just put up, do it like this

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
                BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath, options);
                int imageHeight = options.outHeight;
                int imageWidth = options.outWidth;
                String imageType = options.outMimeType;
                    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options,512,256);//512 and 256 whatever you want as scale
                    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
                Bitmap yourSelectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedImagePath,options);
//Bitmap yourSelectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath);

            File pngDir = new   File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"PicUploadTemp");
            if (!pngDir.exists()) {
            pngDir.mkdirs();
         }

          File pngfile = new File(pngDir,"texture1.jpg");
            FileOutputStream fOut;

            try {
                    fOut = new FileOutputStream(pngfile);

                     yourSelectedImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50,fOut);


            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            new async_upload().execute(pngfile.getPath().toString());
            yourSelectedImage.recycle();
            resizedBitmap.recycle();
            Log.d("INTERNET", yourSelectedImage.toString());
```

Comment: i'll try it now and get back to you.

Comment: Well,it works.I am able to compress the image! Thank you. But how about scaling it down? I've tried decodeUri(Uri.fromFile(pngfile)); but it seems it doesn scale my image.

Comment: i thought you would scale down the bitmap before you compress it, and then use the Uri for the Async, that way the temp file that you compressed is already scaled down and ready to be uploaded

Comment: Yeap,the scope of the question was about the URI which is solved.Thank you!Accepted!