# slow loading, drawing on big picture

Tags: java, android

Hey everyone, i have got a little problem with my code i make app for drawing but i have got a little **troubles** with **big  /large/huge pictures**. I want make my app affective and the best, but this problem make me mad. 
Ok i use bitmap and i draw with canvas, but problem is if i want load pictures and there is a problem:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
        at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
```

and there is code:

```
    public void load() {
    if (mPicturePath != null) {
        FileInputStream in;
        BufferedInputStream buf;
        try {
            loadedBmp=null;
            in = new FileInputStream(mPicturePath);
            buf = new BufferedInputStream(in);
            byte[] bMapArray = new byte[buf.available()];
            buf.read(bMapArray);

            loadedBmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bMapArray, 0,
                    bMapArray.length);

           loadedBmp = resizeImage(loadedBmp);
            delete();
            drawBitmap(loadedBmp);

            updateBitmap(loadedBmp);

            if (in != null) {
                in.close();
            }
            if (buf != null) {
                buf.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error reading file", e.toString());
        }
        // Clear path so we don't load it again next time.
        mPicturePath = null;
    }
}
```

And sacond problem is slow drawing on big pictures, and i dont know where is border to picture if i it crashs .I cant find a solve :(

Comment: do it like this, i mean 320X480 is reasonable, a picture is high resolution being alot of memory, check this out so you can load the bitmap into smaller resolution in memory before loading the whole picture in high resolution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18675565/scale-selected-image-in-android-image-gallery/18675702#18675702

Comment: ok but i need a big picture but i think i dont know what is to lay , and i think if i make picture with width 4800*800 thank crash, or if i load 2000*2000 then crash to, but problem is i cant change width or hight if i change orientation..

Answer (score 0):

To get a Bitmap use Android Query, it will help you in your case, dont make decode array or any stuffs, this one is easy and effective.

Download jar from here: http://code.google.com/p/android-query/

Code:

```
private AQuery androidAQuery;
androidAQuery=new AQuery(this);

    androidAQuery.ajax(YOUR IMAGE URL,Bitmap.class,0,new AjaxCallback<Bitmap>(){
                        @Override
                        public void callback(String url, Bitmap object, AjaxStatus status) {
                            super.callback(url, object, status);

                            //You will get Bitmap from object.
                        }

                    });
```

Comment: Are you sure i need it for this app https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.slikar.slika&hl=sl i want try it better and faster :)

Comment: Ya to get bitmap and loading Image everything is easy with Android Query. You can try it.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this is working great with me.**

```
private String decodeFile(String path) {
        String strMyImagePath = null;
        Bitmap scaledBitmap = null;

        try {
            // Part 1: Decode image
            Bitmap unscaledBitmap = ScalingUtilities.decodeFile(path, DESIREDWIDTH, DESIREDHEIGHT, ScalingLogic.FIT);

            if (!(unscaledBitmap.getWidth() <= 800 && unscaledBitmap.getHeight() <= 800)) {
                // Part 2: Scale image
                scaledBitmap = ScalingUtilities.createScaledBitmap(unscaledBitmap, DESIREDWIDTH, DESIREDHEIGHT, ScalingLogic.FIT);
            } else {
                unscaledBitmap.recycle();
                return path;
            }

            // Store to tmp file

            String extr = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
            File mFolder = new File(extr + "/myTmpDir");
            if (!mFolder.exists()) {
                mFolder.mkdir();
            }

            String s = "tmp.png";

            File f = new File(mFolder.getAbsolutePath(), s);

            strMyImagePath = f.getAbsolutePath();
            FileOutputStream fos = null;
            try {
                fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
                scaledBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 70, fos);
                fos.flush();
                fos.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            scaledBitmap.recycle();
        } catch (Throwable e) {
        }

        if (strMyImagePath == null) {
            return path;
        }
        return strMyImagePath;

    }
```

**Utility Class**

```
public class ScalingUtilities {

    /**
     * Utility function for decoding an image resource. The decoded bitmap will
     * be optimized for further scaling to the requested destination dimensions
     * and scaling logic.
     *
     * @param res The resources object containing the image data
     * @param resId The resource id of the image data
     * @param dstWidth Width of destination area
     * @param dstHeight Height of destination area
     * @param scalingLogic Logic to use to avoid image stretching
     * @return Decoded bitmap
     */
    public static Bitmap decodeResource(Resources res, int resId, int dstWidth, int dstHeight,
            ScalingLogic scalingLogic) {
        Options options = new Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        options.inSampleSize = calculateSampleSize(options.outWidth, options.outHeight, dstWidth,
                dstHeight, scalingLogic);
        Bitmap unscaledBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);

        return unscaledBitmap;
    }
    public static Bitmap decodeFile(String path, int dstWidth, int dstHeight,
            ScalingLogic scalingLogic) {
        Options options = new Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        options.inSampleSize = calculateSampleSize(options.outWidth, options.outHeight, dstWidth,
                dstHeight, scalingLogic);
        Bitmap unscaledBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);

        return unscaledBitmap;
    }

    /**
     * Utility function for creating a scaled version of an existing bitmap
     *
     * @param unscaledBitmap Bitmap to scale
     * @param dstWidth Wanted width of destination bitmap
     * @param dstHeight Wanted height of destination bitmap
     * @param scalingLogic Logic to use to avoid image stretching
     * @return New scaled bitmap object
     */
    public static Bitmap createScaledBitmap(Bitmap unscaledBitmap, int dstWidth, int dstHeight,
            ScalingLogic scalingLogic) {
        Rect srcRect = calculateSrcRect(unscaledBitmap.getWidth(), unscaledBitmap.getHeight(),
                dstWidth, dstHeight, scalingLogic);
        Rect dstRect = calculateDstRect(unscaledBitmap.getWidth(), unscaledBitmap.getHeight(),
                dstWidth, dstHeight, scalingLogic);
        Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(dstRect.width(), dstRect.height(),
                Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(scaledBitmap);
        canvas.drawBitmap(unscaledBitmap, srcRect, dstRect, new Paint(Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG));

        return scaledBitmap;
    }

    /**
     * ScalingLogic defines how scaling should be carried out if source and
     * destination image has different aspect ratio.
     *
     * CROP: Scales the image the minimum amount while making sure that at least
     * one of the two dimensions fit inside the requested destination area.
     * Parts of the source image will be cropped to realize this.
     *
     * FIT: Scales the image the minimum amount while making sure both
     * dimensions fit inside the requested destination area. The resulting
     * destination dimensions might be adjusted to a smaller size than
     * requested.
     */
    public static enum ScalingLogic {
        CROP, FIT
    }

    /**
     * Calculate optimal down-sampling factor given the dimensions of a source
     * image, the dimensions of a destination area and a scaling logic.
     *
     * @param srcWidth Width of source image
     * @param srcHeight Height of source image
     * @param dstWidth Width of destination area
     * @param dstHeight Height of destination area
     * @param scalingLogic Logic to use to avoid image stretching
     * @return Optimal down scaling sample size for decoding
     */
    public static int calculateSampleSize(int srcWidth, int srcHeight, int dstWidth, int dstHeight,
            ScalingLogic scalingLogic) {
        if (scalingLogic == ScalingLogic.FIT) {
            final float srcAspect = (float)srcWidth / (float)srcHeight;
            final float dstAspect = (float)dstWidth / (float)dstHeight;

            if (srcAspect > dstAspect) {
                return srcWidth / dstWidth;
            } else {
                return srcHeight / dstHeight;
            }
        } else {
            final float srcAspect = (float)srcWidth / (float)srcHeight;
            final float dstAspect = (float)dstWidth / (float)dstHeight;

            if (srcAspect > dstAspect) {
                return srcHeight / dstHeight;
            } else {
                return srcWidth / dstWidth;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Calculates source rectangle for scaling bitmap
     *
     * @param srcWidth Width of source image
     * @param srcHeight Height of source image
     * @param dstWidth Width of destination area
     * @param dstHeight Height of destination area
     * @param scalingLogic Logic to use to avoid image stretching
     * @return Optimal source rectangle
     */
    public static Rect calculateSrcRect(int srcWidth, int srcHeight, int dstWidth, int dstHeight,
            ScalingLogic scalingLogic) {
        if (scalingLogic == ScalingLogic.CROP) {
            final float srcAspect = (float)srcWidth / (float)srcHeight;
            final float dstAspect = (float)dstWidth / (float)dstHeight;

            if (srcAspect > dstAspect) {
                final int srcRectWidth = (int)(srcHeight * dstAspect);
                final int srcRectLeft = (srcWidth - srcRectWidth) / 2;
                return new Rect(srcRectLeft, 0, srcRectLeft + srcRectWidth, srcHeight);
            } else {
                final int srcRectHeight = (int)(srcWidth / dstAspect);
                final int scrRectTop = (int)(srcHeight - srcRectHeight) / 2;
                return new Rect(0, scrRectTop, srcWidth, scrRectTop + srcRectHeight);
            }
        } else {
            return new Rect(0, 0, srcWidth, srcHeight);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Calculates destination rectangle for scaling bitmap
     *
     * @param srcWidth Width of source image
     * @param srcHeight Height of source image
     * @param dstWidth Width of destination area
     * @param dstHeight Height of destination area
     * @param scalingLogic Logic to use to avoid image stretching
     * @return Optimal destination rectangle
     */
    public static Rect calculateDstRect(int srcWidth, int srcHeight, int dstWidth, int dstHeight,
            ScalingLogic scalingLogic) {
        if (scalingLogic == ScalingLogic.FIT) {
            final float srcAspect = (float)srcWidth / (float)srcHeight;
            final float dstAspect = (float)dstWidth / (float)dstHeight;

            if (srcAspect > dstAspect) {
                return new Rect(0, 0, dstWidth, (int)(dstWidth / srcAspect));
            } else {
                return new Rect(0, 0, (int)(dstHeight * srcAspect), dstHeight);
            }
        } else {
            return new Rect(0, 0, dstWidth, dstHeight);
        }
    }

}
```